# Recording and Casting permission dialog is getting canceled immediately

Tags: java, android, startactivityforresult, android-mediaprojection

I am developing an android app that requires screen capturing. I am using [MediaProjectionManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/projection/MediaProjectionManager) to take screen shots. The problem is the permission dialog is being displayed for a sec and **closing immediately**.
[Permission Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TE4q8.png)

This is how I am calling the `startActivityForResult`

```
          Intent intent = ((MediaProjectionManager)     activity.getSystemService(Context.MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE)).createScreenCaptureIntent();
            intent.setFlags(0);
            activity.startActivityForResult(intent, RUN_TEST_CODE);
```

So far I've tried

- setting `standard` or `singleTop`  launch mode in Activity.
- setting `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` in Intent
- setting `in.setFlags(0);` in Intent